# Get Ivar value from object in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Can someone post an example of how I get an instance variable value that is a double?
I tried using the object_getIvar() function but that didn't go very well because it seems like this function is only good for variables that return objects and not scalar data type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you already know the name of the instance variable, you can just use [KVC](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html). Say the ivar with double value of an object x is called "weight", you do `NSNumber* x=[obj valueForKey:@"weight"];` then you can get the double value by `[x doubleValue]`.
Similarly, you can set an NSNumber num containing a double value by `[obj setValue:num forKey:@"weight"]`.

`object_getIvar()` is something lower-level, useful to get the class layout and/or getting the type information of an ivar which you only know the name, etc. If KVC isn't sufficient for you, could you explain in more detail exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Since the apple docs aren't clear `valueForKey` does indeed works not only with getters, but also searches ivars as well, and will even intelligently add the underscore for you. See https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-02-08-lets-build-key-value-coding.html

Answer (score 11):

```
/*
 set
 */
Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([self class], "_rate");
((void (*)(id, Ivar, CGFloat))object_setIvar)(self, ivar, rate);

/*
 get
 */
ptrdiff_t offset = ivar_getOffset(ivar);
unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char *)(__bridge void*)self;
CGFloat floatValue = *((CGFloat *)(bytes+offset));
```

Answer (score 5):

While I totally agree with Yuji, and KVC is the correct approach for the vast majority of problems this question probably relates too, in the interest of the small number of cases where you really do want to go poking around in the ivars, the answer is to use `object_getInstanceVariable()` for this. For example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    double _someDouble;
}
@property double someDouble;
@end
@implementation MyObject
@synthesize someDouble=_someDouble;
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    object.someDouble = 3.14;
    double doubleOut;
    object_getInstanceVariable(object, "_someDouble", (void**)&doubleOut);
    NSLog(@"%f", doubleOut);
    [object release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Note the bizarre cast of `double*` to a `void**`. It is correct, required to avoid warnings, and is a side effect of the usual use case where this returns an object pointer.

But you *really* shouldn't be poking around in the ivars in all but a very few cases.

Comment: yes, I think I am now in this case - a plugin for Terminal.app. I know from classdump that TTView has an ivar of _clickedURL, but not expose a property for it. the object_getInstanceVariable/object_setInstanceVariable is what I need, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I will share my answer (its very similar to the previous one, but more simple and supports ARC). I needed to have access to `NSTextStorage` private Ivar but u can use any other class. I used it as a category method of `UIView`

```
 - (NSString *_Nullable)ivarVlaue {
        NSTextStorage *_Nullable txtStrg;
        Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([self class], [@"property_name"   UTF8String]);
        if (!ivar){
           return nil;
        }
        txtStrg = object_getIvar(self, ivar);
        return txtStrg.string;}
```